# cron email if only it fails

Tags: cron

I am receiving email from daily running crontab which executes a php script.
I want it to send me email if only it has errors or fails.

How to do that ?

Note: I am using cpanel to add cron job.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
* * * * * /path/to/cron/script >/dev/null
```

That will send all stdout to /dev/null and should only email you for anything in stderr